# I am getting a java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Server {
    // ArrayList<PrintWriter> writers; // hold a list of current connections
    Set<Socket> sockets = new HashSet<Socket>();
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket sock;
    private static SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    private static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().go();
    }

    public void go() {
        try {
            // setup port listener
            // add connections to arraylist
            // setup in and out streams
            System.out.println("waiting connetion");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8999);
            // writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();

            while (true) {
                sock = serverSocket.accept();
                sockets.add(sock);
                // PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                // sock.getOutputStream());
                // writers.add(writer);
                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(sock));
                t.start();
                System.out.println("connected");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fail setup network");

        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");

        }
    }

    class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private BufferedReader in;

        public ClientHandler(Socket sock) {
            // setup a client connection
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        sock.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                System.out.println("fail classhandler");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // receive and relay messages back to clients
            String message;
            try {
                while ((message = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    shout(message);
                    System.out.println("client says : "
                            + date.format(cal.getTime()) + message);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("closing");
                    sock.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sockets.remove(sock);
                System.out.println(sockets);
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("fail read message");

            }
        }

        public synchronized void shout(String message) {
            // send message to all clients
            // for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
            // writer.println(date.format(cal.getTime()) + " " + message
            // + "\n");
            // writer.flush();
            // }
            for (Socket sock : sockets) {
                try {
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                    writer.println(date.format(cal.getTime()) + " " + message
                            + "\n");
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

=======================================================

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Client {

        private JTextArea tArea;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private Socket sock;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Client().go();
        }

        public void go() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client");
            final JTextField tField = new JTextField(25);
            tArea = new JTextArea(30, 20);
            JButton button = new JButton("send");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    sendMessage(tField.getText());
                    tField.setText("");
                }
            });
            frame.setSize(300, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(tArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(tField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.pack();
            setupNetwork();
            Thread t = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
            t.start();
        }

        public void setupNetwork() {
            try {
                sock = new Socket("localhost", 8999);
                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("fail networking");


}
    }

    class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            //receive messages from server
            try {
                String message = null;
                while ((message = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    tArea.append(message + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("fail incoming reader");

            }
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fail send message");
        }
    }
}
```

when I close a client I get this error and I tried somethings with closing my connections but ultimately I am not sure how to get rid of this error:

```
fail read message
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Server$ClassHandler.run(Server.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know its because I am closing a connection but it keeps throwing this error and its annoying even though it doesn't break my server.

Comment: This is not a solution to your problems but a I suggest you should use Apache Mina to do these sort of things. Because these library handles  low level maintenance on its own and application can concentrate on writing logic.

Answer (score 4):

The usual cause of this is that you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error.

The specific problem here is that when you get `null` from `readLine()` in the server, you should close that socket and remove the corresponding `Writer` from the array of writers to shout at.

Comment: I have been trying at it but I can't come up with how to close the connection or remove it if the user exits the application forcefully

Comment: @CatznDogz You can't find the close() method?

Comment: In your answer, you said that it is because the client is trying to write to already closed connection. But what make the other party (i.e. the server side) close the connection in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you should properly close the socket when you're done with it on the client. I'm not a SWING guru, but looks like [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) is what you need. Just close the connection when main window is closed.

EDIT: When you close TCP socket, there is a little bit of job need to be done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination. When you close the program this is not going to happen. OS will close the connection for you and will free all of the associated resources, but server will not be notified about client closing the connection.

EDIT 2: Demonstration 
Server:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
          try {
              System.out.println("waiting connetion");
              ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8999);
              while (true) {
                  Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                  System.out.println("Connected");
                  Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                          clientSocket.getInputStream());
                  reader.read(); // wait for input
                  System.out.println("No exception");
              }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              System.out.println("Exception");
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
         Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 8999);
         System.out.println("Press 1 to close gracefully, any other nuber otherwise");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         if (sc.nextInt() ==1 ) {
             sock.close();
         } else {
             //do nothing
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It happens *when* he closes a client connection.

Comment: @EJP yes, this happens when he closes the client connection _abruptly_. Server should be properly notified when client closes the connection. This will not happen if it's just resources being feed by OS. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination

Comment: When a process exits the OS closes the TCP connection gracefully, non-abruptly. There is nothing in your non-normative reference that says "this will not happen if it's just resources being freed by OS".

Comment: @EJP You've made me code to prove my point. Check out the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

To tell the java code that all HTTP request should be routed through the proxy use the below snippet:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
     public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return (new PasswordAuthentication("USERNAME","PASSWORD".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

The System.setProperty sets the proxy host and port. The Authenticator should be your corporate username and password. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

put `socketname.close()` method in your client...the problem is that the client gets  finished up before the server could read streams from it...